# Jquery touch swipe event / no jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, swipe, jquery-events, touch-event, hammer.js

I've been looking for a while for a good jQuery library that will allow me to attach touch events to the DOM elements, especially swipe / tap.

I've tried hammer.js, in the documentation it tells that it has swipe effect, but when I try to attach it like `$('.element').on('swipe', function(){ //do smth });` it doesn't work.

I was able to simulate the swipe by using its 'dragend' event, but the bad thing is that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

To be more specific on what I want to achieve - check the twitter website on your phone, and try to swipe left/right a tweet in your timeline/feed, it should reveal some actions buttons for 'Reply' / 'Retweet' / 'Favorite'.

Can anyone give me a code example or a library with good documentation on how I can achieve this?

P.S: I can't use jQuery mobile on this project.

Comment: Yes, i did, and I already tried most of the libraries i found, but I didn't really found one that works good. :(

Answer (score 3):

I can't help you with a library, but I can copy/paste what I use to make a swipe with JQuery.
This exemple is only for a up and down swipe, but quite easy to adapt to other gestures.

This is the plugin part :

```
;(function($) { 
  $.fn.tactile = function(swipe) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(document),
      isTouching = false,
      debut;                                // means start in french

      $this.on('touchstart', debutGeste);       

      function debutGeste() {               // means start of gesture
        if (event.touches.length == 1) {
          debut = event.touches[0].pageY;
          isTouching = true;
          $this.on('touchmove', geste);
        }
      }

      function finGeste() {                 // means end of gesture
        $this.off('touchmove');
        isTouching = false;
        debut = null;
      } 

      function geste() {                   // geste means gesture
        if(isTouching) {
          var actuel = event.touches[0].pageY,
          delta = debut - actuel;

          if (Math.abs(delta) >= 30) {     // this '30' is the length of the swipe
            if (delta > 0) {
              swipe.up();
            } else {
              swipe.down();
            }                       
            finGeste();
          }
        }
        event.preventDefault(); 
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

This is the use part :

```
$(document).tactile({   
  up: function() { }, 
  down: function() { }
});
```

I can't promise this is the right way, neither this is good code, but it works.

Comment: Thanks mdi, I will give it a try and let you know the result ;)

Comment: This code is running on several websites, so I hope it works :) Tell me if you need help to add right/left swipes.

Comment: I will try to adjust it myself (don't want to bother you much). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use jQuery mobile? Can you use Sencha touch? http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/touchevents

Comment: Hi Juans, thanks for the answer. I think that using frameworks like Sencha/jQuery mobile just for the events it's an overkill, doesn't it?

Comment: @StafieAnatolie Not if you're going to build an application that is supposed to look like a mobile app. Both frameworks will do a lot of what you're doing to make your app look mobile friendly. If it's just a page and you want to swipe, then maybe. But it looks like you want to display a list view with buttons that show on swipe, which both frameworks make easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jQuery version of Hammer.js, shouldn't that be:

$('.element').hammer().on('swipe', function(){ //do smth });

I think you need the Hammer object to handle the jQuery specific events. From what I've read, Hammer doesn't inject them as normal custom jQuery events.