# jquery swipe between divs and highlight it in the menu

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, swipe-gesture

This may be a silly question or inappropriate to post it here so please don't punish me.

I'm about to build a one page website targeted for iPad users.

There will be a navigation bar, so when is clicked it will reveal that particular div. Now, I would like to use the swipe "touch" events, so when you swipe the screen the next content(div) will slide-in and the navigation bar will highlight the current page you're on. Also, give an user choice to tap the navigation bar element if they don't want to swipe the screen.

I know jQuery UI has one page ajax solution but without swiping :(

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jquery mobile](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/).

Or refer the following questions.

[Jquery touch swipe event / no jQuery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428433/jquery-touch-swipe-event-no-jquery-mobile)

[Standalone jQuery "touch" method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701139/standalone-jquery-touch-method)